# Extract a string omitting certain characters in java

Tags: java, string, substring

This is my string

1 AP(PEAR + ANC)E (CAN anag)

14 EN(T)ICE (NIECE anag)

15 CHIC ("SHEIK" hom)

The string has an answer hidden,
The first string has an answer APPEARANCE and second string has ENTICE
I must extract those particular answer alone from the strings.
I tried to extract those words from it by

```
String input = "AP(PEAR + ANC)E (CAN anag)";;
String output = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(' '));
System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

AP(PEAR

As you can see, there is a space after R so the sub-string stops there and so the output. But Is there any way to read till the character 'E'(ie. end of string 'APPEARANC**E**') ? I want to stop reading if there is a space **and** if the next character is '(' .

I have another type of string in the same program "EN(T)ICE (NIECE anag)"

```
String input = "EN(T)ICE (NIECE anag)";
String output = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(' '));
System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

EN(T)ICE

There is a space after the character 'E' so it successfully gave the full output. Is there any way to get output like this for the first string. ? Any help would be great !!

Comment: So `input.indexOf(" (")` should do it.

Comment: How to apply the same for this input string ?                                          String input = "CHIC ("SHEIK" hom)"; @Berger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this splitting the string on the index of `" ("`:

```
String input1 = "EN(T)ICE (NIECE anag)";
String input2 = "AP(PEAR + ANC)E (CAN anag)";
String input3 = "CHIC (\"SHEIK\" hom)";

System.out.println(extract(input1));
System.out.println(extract(input2));
System.out.println(extract(input3));

public static String extract(String s){
    return s.split(" \\(.*")[0]
            .replace("(", "")
            .replace(")", "")
            .replace(" + ", "");
}
```

Will produce :

**ENTICE**

**APPEARANCE**

**CHIC**

Comment: Is there any way where I could get  "1 APPEARANCE"  with a digit ?  ie. if the input is  " 22 TIRES (2 defs) " then if I extract numbers alone from it using String num  = a.replaceAll("\\D", "") , I am getting output as "222" but I need only 22 and not any digits which is after the bracket ? @Guillaume

Answer (score 3):

Use `replaceAll` instead of `indexOf` and `substring`.

```
String[] inputs = {
    "AP(PEAR + ANC)E (CAN anag)",
    "EN(T)ICE (NIECE anag)", 
    "CHIC (\"SHEIK\" hom)"};
for (String s : inputs) {
    String output = s.replaceAll(" \\(.*|[()+\\s]", "");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

result:

```
APPEARANCE
ENTICE
CHIC
```

Comment: How about for the string  "CHIC ("SHEIK" hom)" ? @saka1029

Comment: Superb!! Works like a charm @saka1029

Comment: But I am not supposed to add \ for the string CHIC ("SHEIK" hom). As the strings are dynamic ones @saka1029

Comment: The `\\` here are just because of the hard coded string for the sample, you don't have to add them.

Comment: Is there any way where I could get "1 APPEARANCE" with a digit ? ie. if the input is " 22 TIRES (2 defs) " then if I extract numbers alone from it using String num = a.replaceAll("\\D", "") , I am getting output as "222" but I need only 22 and not any digits which is after the bracket ? @saka1029

Comment: Try `" 22 TIRES (2 defs)".replaceAll("^\\D*|\\D.*", "")`

Answer (score 1):

Split on the " (";

like so:

```
String input = "AP(PEAR + ANC)E (CAN anag)";
System.out.println(input.split(" \\(.*")[0]);
```

Just replace the String input with new values!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just replace the `" + "` with nothing, and then split by `" "` (space)?

Something like this:

```
private static String convertInputToOutput(final String input) {
    String[] splittedArray = input.replaceAll(" \\+ ", "").split(" ");
    return splittedArray[0];
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convertInputToOutput("AP(PEAR + ANC)E (CAN anag)"));
    System.out.println(convertInputToOutput("EN(T)ICE (NIECE anag)"));
    System.out.println(convertInputToOutput("CHIC (\"SHEIK\" hom)"));
}
```

Output:

```
AP(PEARANC)E
EN(T)ICE
CHIC
```

---

If you want output without parenthesis, also use a `replaceAll` for the parenthesis:

```
private static String convertInputToOutput(final String input) {
    String[] splittedArray = input.replaceAll(" \\+ ", "").split(" ");
    return splittedArray[0].replaceAll("(", "").replaceAll(")", "");
}
```

Output:

```
APPEARANCE
ENTICE
CHIC
```

Comment: But I am not supposed to add \ for the string CHIC ("SHEIK" hom). As the strings are dynamic ones  @Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: @Anusha Not sure what you mean.. The \ in the String `"CHIC (\"SHEIK\" hom)"` is used to escape the `"`-signs. I just used these hardcoded examples to have full testable code. If you read the from somewhere (like a file), you can just pass that _dynamic_ String into the `convertInputToOutput`-method.